# docker failed to run getting error /bin/sh: 1: tee /opt/app.log: not found

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I Created a docker conatiner for nodejs project docker conatiner failed to run because of the following error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: tee /opt/app.log: not found
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.16.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN chmod 500 /app/init.sh
CMD sh ./init.sh 2>&1 | tee /opt/app.log
```

Comment: Create the /opt/app.log file before using it and check that the `tee` command is installed in the official Node image. If not install it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sending logs to a file in the isolated container filesystem often isn't useful, and Docker will capture the process's stdout on its own.  Can you just run `CMD ["./init.sh"]` without any of the rest?

Comment: This Dockerfile does not produce that error message.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are failing is because `tee /opt/app.log` is interpreted by a single term to `sh` CMD for some reason.

The following Dockerfile uses `ENTRYPOINT` to specify `sh` as the binary that your containerized engine uses, then the arguments within it to do piped redirection the way you are intending:

```
FROM node:14.16.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
RUN chmod 500 ./init.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
CMD ["-c", "./init.sh 2>&1 | tee /opt/app.log"]
```

The following is the contents for my example `init.sh` script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

echo "made it here!"
echo "example stderr" >&2

sleep infinity
```

I use Podman myself, but here are the output of my example commands:

```
~/containerPipedCMD$ sudo podman build -t container-piped-cmd:0.0.2 .
STEP 1/6: FROM node:14.16.1
STEP 2/6: WORKDIR /app
--> Using cache ccbd8b5d1cf9bcefed05e9e4a1c5824f03f8fa1c4bd3f32e1ef6f7c603de0d7a
--> ccbd8b5d1cf
STEP 3/6: COPY . ./
--> 1bc2c5efb0c
STEP 4/6: RUN chmod 500 ./init.sh
--> 757b4540f2e
STEP 5/6: ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
--> 77ecf538749
STEP 6/6: CMD ["-c", "./init.sh 2>&1 | tee /opt/app.log"]
COMMIT container-piped-cmd:0.0.2
--> a5025cfbebe
Successfully tagged localhost/container-piped-cmd:0.0.2
a5025cfbebe557e7c35360821850f591b45bda1ef6c92149ac6d48f0110941d7

~/containerPipedCMD$ sudo podman create --name container-piped-cmd container-piped-cmd:0.0.2
container-piped-cmd

~/containerPipedCMD$ sudo podman start container-piped-cmd
container-piped-cmd

$ sudo podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                                COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS            PORTS       NAMES
e33ce19edc9d  localhost/container-piped-cmd:0.0.2  -c ./init.sh 2>&1...  17 seconds ago  Up 4 seconds ago              container-piped-cmd

$ sudo podman logs container-piped-cmd
made it here!
example stderr

$ sudo podman exec -it container-piped-cmd cat /opt/app.log
made it here!
example stderr
```

However, as the comments suggest, it may just be best to rely on your container's stdout into your containerized engine.